# Is it possible to Remove Directory with some contents using pysftp module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sftp, pysftp

> I am creating a backup script using pysftp module. I am able to upload
>   and download files. When i am trying to Delete a directory with some
>   contents i got an exception.
>
> This is what i tried

```
con = pysftp.Connection('192.168.0.40',username='root',password='clado123')
con.chdir('/root/backup')
con.pwd
con.listdir()
['data', 'test']
data - directory is not empty.
test - directory is empty.
con.rmdir('test')
con.listdir()
['data']
con.rmdir('data')
```

**OSError: Failure**

> Can any one suggest me a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have find out a way. There is method called 'execute' in the pysftp connection object. We can execute commands on remote server using this method.

```
con.execute('rm -rf /root/backup/data')
con.listdir()
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

Other solutions are dependent on the SFTP server operating system. For example, `con.execute('rm xxxx')` won't work if the SFTP server is a windows implementation.

For a pysftp only approach to delete non-empty directories, you can use [`con.walktree`](/root/backup) to recursively delete all regular files while building a list of subdirectories to delete after the files.

You can't directly delete the directories from `walktree` since it visits the deeper levels last, and you need the opposite.

After the `walktree` runs you can iterate (in reverse) over the list of directories and [`rmdir`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.rmdir) each one.

Note that in the code below `fcallback=con.remove` so walktree will call [`remove(remotepath)`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.remove) for each file recursively.

On the other hand, `dcallback=dirs.append` so for each directory will execute `dirs.append(directory_remote_path)` , effectively building the list of directories to delete.

```
import os
import pysftp


sftp_host = os.environ[ 'SFTP_HOST' ]
sftp_username = os.environ[ 'SFTP_USERNAME' ]
sftp_password = os.environ[ 'SFTP_PASSWORD' ]

con = pysftp.Connection(sftp_host, username=sftp_username, password=sftp_password)

dirs = ['/root/backup/data']
con.walktree(dirs[0], fcallback=con.remove, dcallback=dirs.append, ucallback=con.remove, recurse=True)

print(dirs)

for d in reversed(dirs):
    print("Delete directory", d)
    con.rmdir(d)
    
con.close()
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution which is not dependent on platform (while the accepted answer is platform dependent).  It works well in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

`rmdir(remotepath)` found at the documenation http://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.8/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.rmdir

Comment: I have already tried that. rmdir is perfectly working on empty directories, but it is failing on directories with some contents.

Comment: You coud remove every object in the dir first,althought it's not the best solution because your directory might include other directories in it

Comment: got a method   > con.execute('rm -rf /root/backup/data') <  @Stavros Avramidis

Answer (score 0):

`remove` all the files from directory and then use `rmdir` to remove empty directory. Works for me.

```
def clean_dir(sftp, dir, files):
    assert sftp.isdir(str(dir)), "Outbox does not exist!"
    assert files.is_dir(), "Source directory does not exist!"
    for capsule in list(files.iterdir()):
        target = dir / capsule.name
        assert sftp.exists(str(target)), "Target files does not exist!"
        sftp.remove(str(target))
        assert not sftp.exists(str(target)), "Removed file still exists!"
```